# What type of graph is this, and how would I go about programming it in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

[image]

I'm planning on creating a similar graph for each data point in a set where I have clustered the data into 5 clusters and calculated the distance to each centroid.  Each point would represent how far away from the centroid it is relative to the average distance away.  I would also like to create one graph per team where the individual player graphs overlay each other.  Here is a snippet of the dataset that I'm using.

[image]

If this isn't the best way to display this sort of data, could you also explain which ways are better and how to do it?

Comment: Called a spider or radar plot. Google R and either of those terms and you'll see lots of examples

Comment: Thank you very much @ekstroem

Answer (score 2):

A very interesting R package for **interactive** radar (o spider) charts is `radarchart`.
Here is a very simple code which gives you the opportunity to appreciate the potentiality of this tool. Let's enjoy it !

```
library(radarchart)
set.seed(12345)
X <- as.data.frame(round(matrix(runif(35),nrow=5),2))
names(X) <- c("Kaydop","Matt","kuxir97","Freakii","Jacob","JKnaps","Mognus")
labs <- paste("DistToC", 1:5)

chartJSRadar(scores=X, labs=labs)
```

[image]